# installing odoo 9 beta gives blank page

Tags: postgresql, odoo

I installed odoo 9 beta from deb http://nightly.odoo.com/9.0/nightly/deb/ 
the install went succesful, and I can start both postgresql and odoo.
when I try to open http://localhost:8069 I get a blank page.
There are no errors in the odoo-server.log.

I tried several installs with differnt nighties, on both ubuntu 10.04 as 15.04 and also directly from github, but I always get a blank page (without errors).

I also tried installing odoo locally with the windows installer and there are no problems, I can access the odoo webpage in windows, but that is no solution because my servers run linux.

So my question is: how can I get to see the odoo website, when installed on ubuntu linux.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not appending `/web` it will automatically redirected to the desired url. if you have no database in the system it will go to 
`http://0.0.0.0:8069/web/database/manager` else it will be redirected to `http://0.0.0.0:8069/web/database/selector` if you do not have any active session on the browser.

Comment: not in my case. I installed it several times on linux, and with http://localhost:8069 I only got a blank page. it is just when I added http://localhost:8069/web/database/manager that I was able to see something. After that I could ommit it, but for the first time it was apparantly needed. Maybe this is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

you need to append /web at the base url

like this: http://localhost:8069/web

This is NOT documented by odoo, and the many install guides on the web!!